# Sending mail via .net core smtpClient: SmtpException / FormatException

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, smtp, smtpclient

I'm trying to send mails via SmtpClient in .net core. Basically I'm just migrating some old .net framework code to .net core. In the old system it's done in the following way:

```
using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.xyz.de", 587))
{
   smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
   smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
   smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
   smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
}
```

This code is working fine.

Now I migrated this code to .net core like below:

```
 using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.xyz.de", 587))
 {
    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;  
    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
 }
```

The first issue is now that I get an error message:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Stack trace:

```
   at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpNegotiateAuthenticationModule.GetSecurityLayerOutgoingBlob(String challenge, NTAuthentication clientContext)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpNegotiateAuthenticationModule.Authenticate(String challenge, NetworkCredential credential, Object sessionCookie, String spn, ChannelBinding channelBindingToken)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

Because of that error I tried to convert the user and passwort strings to Base64 like below:

```
using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.xyz.de", 587))
{
   var userEncoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("user"));
   var passwordEncoded = convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("password"));

   smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
   smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userEncoded, passwordEncoded, "domain");
   smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;               
   smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);              
}
```

Doing this I get another error:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated

Stack trace:

```
   at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)
   at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at MailTest.Program.ProgramStart() in C:\Repos\MailTest\MailTest\Program.cs:line 67
```

Creation of the MailMessage object:

```
mailMessage = new MailMessage("sender@xyz.com", "recipient@xyz.com", "subject", "body");
```

Can anyone figure out, what I am doing wrong? For me the code looks exactly the same except the conversion to Base64.

Comment: What is the stack trace for the first error?

Comment: You do not convert the user name and password.  They are automatically sent secure using NetworkCredentials.

Comment: i have added the stack traces in my post

Comment: @jdweng but then i get this error regarding the Base64 string

Comment: First send a simple text message to see if it works.  The error indicates the MailMessage object has issues.  Need to see the code.  Are you sending HTML message or Text message.  Do you have an attachment?  The mrom address of the message and the SMTP credentials have to match (a change from 3.5 to 4.0).  HTML has special characters. The Base64 string indicates you added text to message that has html special characters.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: @jdweng I have added the creation of a simple MailMessage object without any special characters to my post. But after this change i still get the same error.

Comment: Are you sending more than one email and the first is working and 2nd isn't?  When going to Net 4.0 there was an issue the you could not use the same SMTPClient for two different messages.  You had to crate a new client for each email.

Comment: No I‘m just sending one email so that can‘t be the reason.

Comment: Another idea: There is a "$" (dollar sign) in the password. Can this cause the issue?

Comment: Another observation: When I'm leaving out the port in the in the initialization of the SmptClient, I'm able to send emails. But I'm not sure if leaving out the port means that the authorization at the smtp server is skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself:

It's embarassing and I feel ashamed, but all the tests I did I was using the wrong password. It just never came to my mind because of the irritating error message :(

Comment: Classic! You never do this mistake twice ;)