# Sending email via .net core on ubuntu return base64 error

Tags: c#, ubuntu, base64, smtpclient

I'm having an error when I try to send an email through my test server which is running on ubuntu 16.04. I have a pro account on OVH and I'm using this smtp :

```
pro1.mail.ovh.net
```

When I'm on debug on my workstation running on windows 10, I can send my email.

Here is my code :

```
      var smtp = m_emailConfiguration["Smtp"];
      var email = m_emailConfiguration["Email"];
      var password = m_emailConfiguration["Password"];

      try
      {              
        using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtp, 587))
        {
          var mailMessage = new MailMessage(email, mailTo, subject, body);

          smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
          smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(email, password);
          smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;               
          smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);              
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        throw new Exception(ex.InnerException.Message);
      }
```

I'm having this error :

```
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters
```

Full stack trace :

```
Exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpNegotiateAuthenticationModule.GetSecurityLayerOutgoingBlob(String challenge, NTAuthentication clientContext)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpNegotiateAuthenticationModule.Authenticate(String challenge, NetworkCredential credential, Object sessionCookie, String spn, ChannelBinding channelBindingToken)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

I found someone whose got the same problem : [Sending mail via .net core smtpClient: SmtpException / FormatException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54218912/sending-mail-via-net-core-smtpclient-smtpexception-formatexception)

But his problem was the password, I'm sure that my password is correct.

So is there someone whose got an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Post the full exception, not only the message part. You can get that easily with `Exception.ToString()`. That includes all inner exceptions *and* the call statck. In fact, you should probably remove that catch block entirely as it doesn't handle the exception apart from *hiding* important information.

Comment: As for the error, it's pretty clear. The string you tried to send is bad, and the exception explains why. You didn't post the code that creates that string or its contents though, so it's not possible to say what's wrong. This has little to do with SmtpClient or Ubuntu

Comment: Finally, the [documentation page for SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.8) itself explains it's obsolete and [should be replaced](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0005.md) with [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit). What are you trying to send? MailKit may be able to send the original payload directly and encode it as necessary

Comment: For example, you can add both a plain text and HTML body with images easily [using the BodyBuilder class](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Creating-Messages.htm#UsingBodyBuilder).

Comment: Now that I see the call stack, it looks like SmtpClient tried to use Windows authentication to connect and something went wrong with the token it tried to use. Do you really want to troubleshoot this or switch to MailKit directly? The [Sending Messages](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit#sending-messages) example in the landing page shows how easy it is to authenticate.

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, like I said, it works on windows so I'm wondering why not on Linux, I edit my post the show the full stack trace. I just want to send a generated string so it doesn't contains images...

Comment: I'll give a try to MailKit :-)

Comment: I already explained that SmptClient is obsolete. It may be a bug, that caused the class to try Windows authentication first. MS won't fix it, precisely because it's obsolete. Microsoft itself recommends MailKit

Comment: Yes ok, thanks I'll switch to mailkit to see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's put all the comments in an answer.

Don't use SmptClient. Use [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) instead. [SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.8)  is obsolete and Microsoft itself [recommends](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0005.md) using [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit#sending-messages) or another library.

The call stack shows that the error was raised while trying to authenticate using *Windows* authentication. That's clearly wrong in this case but the bug will probably not be fixed precisely because the class is obsolete.

The [Sending Messages](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit#sending-messages) example shows how easy it is to send messages :

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient ()) {
    // For demo-purposes, accept all SSL certificates (in case the server supports STARTTLS)
    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s,c,h,e) => true;

    client.Connect ("smtp.friends.com", 587, false);

            // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
    client.Authenticate ("joey", "password");

    client.Send (message);
    client.Disconnect (true);
}
```

MailKit is built on top of MimeKit which means it can create complex messages easily. Copying from [another example](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Creating-Messages.htm#UsingBodyBuilder), you can use the `BodyBuilder` utility class to create a message containing both a plain text body and an HTML body with images.

```
        var message = new MimeMessage ();
        message.From.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Joey", "joey@friends.com"));
        message.To.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Alice", "alice@wonderland.com"));
        message.Subject = "How you doin?";

        var builder = new BodyBuilder ();

        // Set the plain-text version of the message text
        builder.TextBody = @"Hey Alice,
....
-- Joey
";

        // In order to reference selfie.jpg from the html text, we'll need to add it
        // to builder.LinkedResources and then use its Content-Id value in the img src.
        var image = builder.LinkedResources.Add (@"C:\Users\Joey\Documents\Selfies\selfie.jpg");
        image.ContentId = MimeUtils.GenerateMessageId ();

        // Set the html version of the message text
        builder.HtmlBody = string.Format (@"<p>Hey Alice,<br>
....
<p>-- Joey<br>
<center><img src=""cid:{0}""></center>", image.ContentId);

        // We may also want to attach a calendar event for Monica's party...
        builder.Attachments.Add (@"C:\Users\Joey\Documents\party.ics");

        // Now we just need to set the message body and we're done
        message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Panagiotis Kanavos in comments said, SmtpClient is deprecated. I use MailKit instead and it works fine now.