# Sending email through Visual Studio C# (Window Form)

Tags: c#

I am creating a C# program.

I would like to sending email while users press the link.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

        private void lblForgotPw_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            var fromAddress = new MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com", "myName");
            var toAddress = new MailAddress("receipt@gmail.com", "receiptName");
            const string fromPassword = "Password";
            const string subject = "SubjectContent";
            const string body = "BodyContent";

            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
            };
            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body
            })
            {
                smtp.Send(message);
            }
}
```

While, I run the program , it appers System.FormatException '指定字串不在電子郵件地址的必要表單中。'.
How should I solve the problems?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error message of the exception?  Which specific operation produces the exception?  What are the observed runtime values for the variables used in that operation?

Comment: According to google translate the Chinese text means "The specified string is not in the required form of an email address."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please separate the concerns of handling a buttonclick and sending mail into separate classes.

also, did you verify the password? :-)
[Sending mail via .net core smtpClient: SmtpException / FormatException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54218912/sending-mail-via-net-core-smtpclient-smtpexception-formatexception)

a FormatException usually indicates something isn't in the expected format, i.e. an email adress without an '@' character or without a domain, or a blank string that should contain a value, etc. etc.